# Multibinding. How to update correct value to source?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

My issue is as follows.

I have 3 Textboxes bound to 3 fields in a Dataset. **TextBox_Rate** , **TextBox_Hours** , **TextBox_Salary** .

What i needed was for **TextBox_Rate** + **TextBox_Hours** to be = **TextBox_Salary** .

I found out that this can be achieved by use of a **Multibinding** and a **Converter** .

The Multibinding looks as follows:

```
<TextBox FontSize="14.667" HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SalaryConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnExceptions="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" StringFormat="C">
            <Binding Path="Rate Per Hour"/>
            <Binding Path="Hours Per Month"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And the Converter:

```
Public Class SalaryConverter
Implements IMultiValueConverter

Dim weeklyHours As Double = 0

Public Function Convert(ByVal values() As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert
    Dim salary As Decimal = 0
    If values(0).Equals(System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) Or values(1).Equals(System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) Then
        Return salary
    Else
        salary = (Math.Round(values(0) * (values(1) * 4)))
        weeklyHours = values(1)
        Return salary
    End If
End Function

Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetTypes() As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Dim testVal As Decimal = CType((value.ToString.Replace("R ", "").Replace(",", "") / weeklyHours), Decimal) / 4
    Return New Object() {testVal}
End Function
```

End Class

All this works 100%. I am getting the results which i want. But this is also where the problem comes in...

**TextBox_Rate** is bound to Dataset field **Rate**, **TextBox_Hours** is bound to Dataset field **Hours** and originally (before the multibinding) **TextBox_Salary** was bound to Dataset field **Salary** but is nou bound to **TextBox_Rate** AND **TextBox_Hours**. And the value produced from the Multibinding is not updated back to the source field "Salary" since it isnt bound that field.

How do i set the binding to update that field?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What language are you using? I believe it is VB.NET.... maybe you should add tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution?

I simply discarded the idea of updaitng the correct binding.

Just like in the converter, anywhere where i need the "Salary" i use the combination of the "Rate" and the "Hours".

Seems to be working.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to save the salary if you are always going to derive the value in any case. This also confirms your choice of discarding the "updating of salary via data binding"

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional binding, eg. bind to TextBox_Hours (one way), TextBox_Rate (one way) and the dataset Salary (two way, or one way to source). Then implement the ConvertBack method of converter to provide a value to dataset and Binding.DoNothing to both textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Or, even simpler, define Salary as a read-only, calculated property of the DataSet.
Then you can bind your TextBoxSalary text box to this property, dispense with your converter altogether, removing the associated business logic from your view.